# Configure Spring boot PropertiesLauncher to do recursive search in classloader paths

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, classloader

I'm using Spring boot (1.3.7) PropertiesLauncher classloader to be able to manually add folders into the classpath with the help of loader.path property.

I have the need of a recursive folder search of jar files in folders configured in loader.path property (add jar files that are present in subfolders).

I had to patch PropertiesLauncher class (getClassPathArchives(String)) to manually set the recursive flag of ExplodedArchive to true (instead of false):

> Archive archive = new ExplodedArchive(file, **<del>false</del>true**)

and everything seem to be working perfectly...

**Is there a reason why this recursive mode is not configurable ?** I'm just hoping it is not going to cause problems somewhere else.

Thanks